# Fail2Ban Testing

Tags: apache-2.2, fail2ban

Running the following testing script to see if Fail2ban is working:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache*/*access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf
```

I get this response:

```
Running tests                                                                                                                                
=============                                                                                                                                

Use ignoreregex line : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-badbots                                                                                
No section headers in /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
```

It is not running the test sweep of my logs.  I have tested my SSH fail2ban setup  with similar syntax and its testing fine.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem you are having is because of the way that the shell is expanding

```
/var/log/apache*/*access.log
```

And I assume that you really meant `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf` too.

Try putting single quotes around that parameter

```
fail2ban-regex '/var/log/apache*/*access.log' /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf
```

which will pass it unexpanded to `fail2ban-regex`.

---

Further research - it doesn't look like `fail2ban-regex` takes wildcards:

```
fail2ban-regex '/var/log/apache*/*access.log' /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf
...
Use regex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf
Use single line: /var/log/apache*/*access.log
```

Note that it thinks we're passing a single line, then try

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf    
...
Use regex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf
Use log file   : /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Note it sees we've passed a log file.

Comment: That didn't seem to help.

Comment: What do you mean by `didn't seen to help` - what;s not right now ?

Comment: It did test correctly when I took out the wildcard. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bth - if this A solved your issue you can mark it as the accepted A so everyone knows it's the solution.. There's a little check mark under the votes for the A if you're not sure how to do it.